# python unittest split tests over several files

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

simplified:

**folder structure**

```
package 
     ./__init__.py 
     ./code/extract.py 
     ./code/transform.py 
     ./code/__init__.py 
     ./test/package_test.py 
     ./test/extract_test.py  
     ./test/transform_test.py
```

**currently: package.py test contains:**

```
import unittest

class PackageTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Base(self):
        self.assertEqual(4,4)

class extractTest(PackageTest):
    
    def test_extractStart(self):
        self.assertEqual(5,5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**I would like to split the test file**

**so package_test.py test only contains:**

```
import unittest

class PackageTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_Base(self):
        self.assertEqual(4,4)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**and extract_test.py test only contains:**

```
class extractTest(PackageTest):
    
    def test_extractStart(self):
        self.assertEqual(5,5)
```

But how do I adjust the unittest.main function so it looks also for a classes inheriting from PackageTest Class?

Comment: You don't have to. `unittest` should be looking for classes derived from `unittest.TestCase`.

Comment: but when I split the files, unittest only tests the package_test.py file

Comment: So how do you call unittest?

Comment: **python -m unittest package_test.py extract_test.py** did the trick,  when you asked: how do you call unittest, my penny dropped, thanks

Answer (score 0):

thank to quamrana's hint: I realised to include the split files into the console command, silly :(

```
$ python -m unittest package_test.py extract_test.py
```